# Using python 2 or 3, matplotlib and tkinter causes an extra empty window to open on calling plt.show()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making an interactive data analysis tool that I am having trouble with (in `python 2.7`, `3.4` and `3.5`). The full program makes graphs that the user has to interact with and then close. It also requires the user to input files via a filechooser.

The issue is whenever I use `plt.show()` an additional small window opens (which I don't want) along with the graph. The small window then has to be closed too, to continue the program. Not that big a deal, but there are many graphs to interact with, so it is a bit off a pain always closing two windows.

If the `Tkinter.Tk().withraw()` is uncommented only the plot opens, but now the program just hangs upon closing the graph and I have to kill the process.

Any ideas for how I might get around this problem?

Thanks in advance. Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
try:
    import Tkinter
except (ImportError):
    import tkinter as Tkinter
try:
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except (ImportError):
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()

print(askopenfilename())


x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I solved it myself after a bit of poking around in the matplotlib source. I tried changing the matplotlib backend to gtk3cairo. I guess the `Tk().withdraw()` was also affecting the matplotlib backend. Works on my linux distro but still need to test it on windows. If I find a solution that works on both I will update the answer.

**EDIT:** `matplotlib.use("Qt4agg")` worked on my windows version. I alo got it work on linux by installing pyside. Doesn't work with the latest version of python3 unfortunatly

Working code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("gtk3cairo")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
try:
    import Tkinter
except (ImportError):
    import tkinter as Tkinter
try:
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except (ImportError):
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()

print(askopenfilename())


x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show(fig1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try naming the figure as maybe it's getting confused as to what you are referring to when you ask it to show a figure

```
x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show(fig1)
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't work. For now I might look for another filechooser.

Comment: @BBulfin I reran your code and yes, you're right, there's the small 'tk' named window that opens. I assumed you meant that it opened two plotting windows and only drew to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, it looks like the extra window is a root window. This link explains it:

https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/768419-askopenfilename-tkfiledialog-problem

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root)
file_read = file.read()  #reads file
```

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your efforts. This method is actually how I ran into the problem. Thus the commented out Tk().withraw(). When you include this root.withdraw() statement no extra window pops up but then the whole program just hangs/freezes when you try to close the plot window.